# javascript variable or database data

Tags: javascript, web-services, variables, web, struct

I have native javascript software. I am requesting a value input from the user and checking if a value has been entered from an array with 1000 elements.

option A;

I have defined 1000 elements one by one in the current js file and when the user presses the button, I see if the value is here. In this way, every time a button is pressed, it does not send a request, there is no traffic on the network side, but because 1000 elements are defined, the js file takes up 50% more space.

option B;

Adding these 1000 elements to the table I created in the database, defining a function in js, sending a value of 1-0 as a result and taking action accordingly. This reduces the js file by at least 50% as code, but it sends a request to the web service and makes network traffic in every call.

Which is more suitable as best practice?

Or how would you suggest a different way?

[image]

[image] **network connection detect**

---

**Not network any different connection**

[image] **js variable connection file**

Comment: Is the data something you need to store in a database? If it is then option 2 otherwise option 1. Unless you want to learn how to access data from a database then also option 2. So "it depends".

Comment: There's also this. When I add or delete a new element, do I go and edit it in the code, it is faster and easier to manage from the database.

Comment: You're answering your own question. You seem determined to use a database.